# helloworld monodevelop 3.0.2 throws exception

Tags: monodevelop

think I followed the Xamarin hello world tutorial but when I launch against the IOS Simulator the following exception is thrown:

**this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key lblOutlet.**

well all the Outlet code was generated from IB and do not tell me to not use IB as that is a big attraction of Mono. The code looks like:using MonoTouch.Foundation;

```
namespace hello
{
    [Register ("helloViewController")]
   partial class helloViewController
   {
       [Outlet]
       MonoTouch.UIKit.UIButton btnClickMe { get; set; }

       [Outlet]
       MonoTouch.UIKit.UILabel lblOutput { get; set; }

       [Action ("actnButtonlick:")]
       partial void actnButtonlick (MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject sender);
```